# Not able to access service by service name on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am using below manifest. I am having a simple server which prints pod name on `/hello`. Here, I was going through kubernetes documentation and it mentioned that we can access service via service name as well. But that is not working for me. As this is a service of type `NodePort`, I am able to access it using IP of one of the nodes. Is there something wrong with my manifest?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myhttpserver
  labels:
    day: zero
    name: httppod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: httppod
      day: zero
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        day: zero
        name: httppod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myappcont
          image: agoyalib/trial:tryit
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: servit
  labels:
    day: zeroserv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    day: zero
    name: httppod
  ports:
    - name: mine
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8090
```

Edit: I created my own mini k8s cluster and I am doing these operations on the master node.

Comment: How are you accessing via service name ? Can you post the curl command.

Comment: curl servit:<port>/hello

Comment: Digged a little more and realized that when I am trying to use service name, it is not contacting coreDNS but a local DNS configured on the VM. That is why the problem. If we exec into any pod, then coreDNS will be accessed and thats when the service name will get resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand when you say

> As this is a service of type NodePort, I am able to access it using IP of one of the nodes

You're accessing your service from outside your cluster. That's why you can't access it using its name.

To access a service using its name, you need to be inside the cluster.

Below is an example where you use a pod based on centos in order to connect to your service using its name :

```sh
# Here we're just creating a pod based on centos
$ kubectl run centos --image=centos:7 --generator=run-pod/v1 --command sleep infinity

# Now let's connect to that pod 
$ kubectl exec centos -ti bash
[root@centos /]# curl servit:8080/hello
```

Comment: Actually I am on the master node only and accessing from that. I have my own mini setup of kubernetes.

Comment: Beiing on the master node does not mean you're inside the cluster. You're just connected on a VM. To be **in the cluster** means you have to be **connected to a pod**

Comment: I just edited the answer in order to add an example with some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be inside cluster meaning you can access it from another pod.

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 test-nslookup --image=busybox:1.28 --rm -it -- nslookup servit
```